# Perl using regular expressions to identify file extensions in a list of files

Tags: regex, perl

I have a long list of files and I am trying to make decisions based on their extensions. This whole thing has to be part of a perl-program of mine. Here is an example for the list:

```
a.pj
b.pj
null
c.xlsx
gibberishWithNoExtension
d.pj
f.docx 
g.pj 1.17 and 1.15.1.1
```

The decision rules are:

```
1) If the extension is ".pj" do something.
2) If the extension is anything else do something else
3) If there is something else after the extension (like version numbers) or there is no extension at all: ignore it
```

The first point should be fairly easy. I guess it would look like this:

```
my $string = a.pj;
if ($string =~ /.pj/) {
    say 'success!'
}
```

But I am stuck on the other cases. Especially when it comes to identifying point 3. Could some of you help me to find the right regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems easier to check 3 before 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/\.pj$/) {
        print "Doing something with $_\n";

    } elsif (/ / || ! /\./) {
        print "Ignoring $_\n";

    } else {
        print "Doing something else with $_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
a.pj
b.pj
null
c.xlsx
gibberishWithNoExtension
d.pj
f.docx
g.pj 1.17 and 1.15.1.1
```

Note the backslash in the first regex. Bare dot matches anything but newline, but you don't want to match `a.xpj`. The dollar sign is needed to prevent matching `a.pjx`.

Comment: I am quite happy with your solution, but I just stumbled over a case where it is not working. There is a file which contains no whitespaces but does contain a version number after the extension (something like: `xyz.pj1.4.0`) how could I catch that?

Comment: @UsefulUserName: How do you want to classify it? As 1, 2, or 3? Or do you want to add a new class for such cases?

Comment: Case 3. I need to kick out/ignore anything that is not formatted properly.

Comment: @UsefulUserName: How can you tell whether `abc.x1` is a file name or a file name with a version number with whitespace missing?

Comment: If you are thinking I'm guessing, you are right. ;) But `.xlsx1.4.0` does not look like an extension for me. I'm going to check with my principal. Hold on.

Comment: Yeah they will have to be ignored. Found some more with `.zip1.3`, `docx2.4` and so on.

Comment: @UsefulUserName: What about `} elsif (/ |[0-9]\.[0-9]+$/ || !/\./) {` for Ignoring? It might also work without the `/ |` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

[File::Basename](http://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Basename)'s `fileparse` can handle this. Give it the regex up want to use and it breaks up the filename:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Basename qw(fileparse);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my( $name, $dir, $suffix ) = fileparse( $_, qr/\.[^.]+\z/ );
    say "$_ -> $suffix";
}
```

You mention that you want to ignore some endings as extensions. You can tailor the regex to do that.

Once you have the extension you can branch on that any way that you like.

Answer (score 1):

I known that you have a good asnwer, but I would like to do something like this:

```
open (INP, "<path_of_file/file_list.txt") or die $!:
while( <INP> ) {
    chomp ( $_ );
    #~ whatever followed by dot '\.', then extension captured in a group '$1'
    #~ line must be evaluated as true only if its ended with a extension name
    #~ otherwise it'll be ignored (as you expect to do)
    if ( $_ =~ m/\.(.+)$/ ) {
        if( $1 eq "pj" ) { #~ 1) If the extension is ".pj" do something.
            #~ do something with pj extension
        } elsif ( $1 eq "xlsx" ) { # and other 'elses' rule 2)
            #~ do something with xlsx extension
        } elsif ( $1 eq "docx" ) {
            #~ do something with docx extension
        } elsif ( $1 eq "..." ) {
            #~ do something with ... extension
        } else {
            #~ do something with not expected extension
        }
    else { #~ rule 3) If there is something else after the extension
        #~ not a text formated as a file name followed by extension
    }
}
close (INP);
```

The reason to do something like this is that you need only one regex evaluation to perform what you want for each file extension you expect to handle.

Comment: I had thought about something like that. The problem is that I don't know and never will know all the extensions contained in the list. And even if I did, the script might be used with other lists that contain yet different files with different extensions. Thank you though, it would have been a very neat solution.